# how to add opening html tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your help.

I want to add an opening html tag before an element and it's closing tag after that element .

this is my script

```
$("#searchresult").append("<span class='addRemoveTag'>");
$("#searchresult").append(checkBoxes[index]);
$("#searchresult").append($(element));
$("#searchresult").append("</span>");
```

but unfortunately  after I add the opening tag the browser close it immediately.

so please could you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: why not `.append("<span class='addRemoveTag'>"+checkBoxes[index]+$(element)+"</span>");`

Comment: @Cattla — Because `checkBoxes[index]` and `$(element)` are not strings.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't.

jQuery operates on the DOM. It allows you to write HTML as an abstraction, but when it gets translated to a DOM, it has to deal in elements, not tags.

---

Build up your DOM piece by piece. Then append it to the document.

```
var $span = $("<span>").addClass("addRemoveTag");
$span.append(checkBoxes[index]);
$span.append(element);
$("#searchresult").append($span);
```

Comment: @Quentin what about `jQuery.wrap` ?

Comment: @pomeh — It doesn't appear to have much relevance to the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

jquery's [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function is awesome

```
$( ".inner" ).wrap( "<div class='new'></div>" );
```

creates:

```
<div class='new'>
    <div class='inner'>yeah, doge</div>
</div>
```

or

```
$(element)
    .add($(checkBoxes[index]))
    .appendTo($('<span class="addRemoveTag" />'));
```